# How to match text in between two words(a..b) till the first occurence of the ending word(b)

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

Can anyone help me to match the text between **From** and first occurrence of **Subject** from the following set of lines,

**Input**

```
Random Line 1
Random Line 2
From: person@example.com
Date: 01-01-2011
To: friend@example.com
   Subject: This is the subject line
Random Line 3
Random Line 4
   Subject: This is subject
This is the end
```

**Output**

```
From: person@example.com
Date: 01-01-2011
To: friend@example.com
   Subject: This is the subject line
```

I tried with the following regular expression,

```
/(From:.*(?i)Subject:.*?)\n/m
```

The above regexp selects till the last Subject

Comment: @AvinashRaj I haven't worked much in Regular Expression. Can you explain me in detail about dotall modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (see: http://rubular.com/r/Lw9rhfwVGt):

```
/(From.*?Subject.*?)\n/m
```